Proper way to attach a Gtk.Popover to an arbitrary widget in GTK4
I have some cases where I need to show a popover on certain mouse events on some Label and Image widgets.
MenuButton isn't exactly appropriate, because it isn't exactly a button, and in some cases I need the menu to be shown on right click, not left click.
I found this in the gtk3 to 4 upgrade guide

In GTK 3, a GtkPopover could be attached to any widget, using the relative-to property. This is no longer possible in GTK 4. The parent widget has to be aware of its popover children, and manage their size allocation. Therefore, only widgets with dedicated popover support can have them, such as GtkMenuButton or GtkPopoverMenuBar.
If you want to make a custom widget that has an attached popover, you need to call gtk_popover_present() in your Gtk.WidgetClass.size_allocate vfunc, in order to update the positioning of the popover.

But this isn't actually mentioned in the documentation for Gtk.Popover itself. And it seems to mostly work if I do something like:
        button = Gtk.Label.new("Click Me!")
        menu = Gtk.PopoverMenu.new_from_model_full(
            self.model, Gtk.PopoverMenuFlags.NESTED
        )
        menu.set_parent(button)
        menu.set_position(Gtk.PositionType.LEFT)

But I'm not sure if there is some problem with that that I am missing.
Is it really necessary to create a custom widget just to attach a popover to an existing widget?
And if I do need to do that, what methods do I need to delegate to the inner label or image? I haven't found a good tutorial on composing widgets that doesn't use template xml.
